# Iniciando GIT pelo Terminal

Tags: git, ubuntu, ftp, terminal

Estou tentando dar git init pelo terminal e quando eu digito esse comando ele acusa que já existe a pasta 'config' e '.git', etc. Além disso quando eu tento usar o git add * ele demora para adicionar o arquivo, agora não sei se é por causa do erro do git init ou porque estou fazendo isso direto no servidor FTP.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você dá um "ls -la", estes arquivos que o git acusa estão lá? Se sim, você pode remover manualmente com um "rm -rf".

Mas, o que exatamente você quer fazer? Iniciar um repositório GIT? Ou apenas usar um que já existe? Talvez o Git init não seja o que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você queira iniciar um novo projeto git, primeiro verifique se já existe a pasta .git no local onde inicializará o seu git com o comando `ls -la`.

Se não existir a pasta basta iniciar o projeto. `git init`

-

**Caso já exista um projeto git:**

Para iniciar novamente um git do zero, primeiramente você precisa remover o git anterior com o comando `rm -r .git`.

Feito isso, em seguida é só criar o git normalmente: `git init`.

Para adicionar todos os arquivos para seu stage eu aconselho usar `git add .` ao invés de `git add *` e caso tenha arquivos deletados que também precisam ser versionados utilize o comando `git add -u` para adicionar todos os arquivos deletados ao stage ou utilize `git add --all` para adicionar todos os arquivos ***(modificados, novos, deletados)*** ao stage.

Em seguida é só comitar e enviar para seu repositório.